# What does 2 commas after variable name mean in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Recently I came across this syntax:

```
${reportName,,}
```

I could not find anything by googling, so does anyone know what does those ,, mean?

Comment: In your terminal, type `man bash`, then hit the slash (`/`) to search, then hit the comma twice, then hit Enter. Documentation is easy!

Comment: @ghoti -- unless all you have is Bash v3.x (like macOS does) in which case the man page is no help at all.  
You'll need to the docs for Bash version 4.x

Comment: @DouglasDD, certainly one will be limited by the version one is using. But documentation is generally installed with the software it's for. The OP mentioned using Linux, and the question was about a specific feature that *would* be documented if the version of bash on his system supported the feature.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

This is called "Parameter Expansion" available in bash version 4+ . To change the case of the string stored in the variable to lower case.Eg:

```
var=HeyThere
echo ${var,,}
heythere
```

You may want to try some additional commands and check the effect:

```
${var^}
${var^^}
${var,}
${var,,}
```

Note: "Parameter Expansion" is present in `man bash` .Search for it.

https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Comment: Thanks. Can you also suggest how to search such things? ",," isn't search-able in google and "man bash" didn't give that. Edit: thanks again, found it in "man bash" after all.

Comment: Please add a note on the `bash` version it is supported from.

Comment: Take care; `~` and `~~` are currently undocumented, so I would avoid them.

Comment: @chepner removed, better to be safe.

Comment: Find them in [Bash reference manual →3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

Comment: For the curious, `~` and `~~` are described [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#case_modification).

Comment: I removed a broken link to http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe from this answer. And added this one https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion.

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned by P... this is parameter expansion. Examples below.

```
myword="Hello"
echo ${myword^}  # first letter uppercase
echo ${myword^^} # all uppercase
echo ${myword,}  # first letter lowercase
echo ${myword,,} # all lowercase
echo ${myword~}  # reverses the case for the first letter
echo ${myword~~} # reverses the case for every letter
```

Output:

```
Hello
HELLO
hello
hello
hello
hELLO
```

Comment: good addition to the top answer, plus one.

Comment: Note that `~` and `~~` are *still* undocumented, as of Feb 2024. They don't officially exist.